# Understanding pipe function in JavaScript (functional programming)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition

I'm working through [question 11](https://bigfrontend.dev/problem/what-is-composition-create-a-pipe) on bfe.dev's JavaScript coding exercises. The question asks to chain multiple basic math functions together via composition.

Here's some sample code that passes the provided test cases.

```
function pipe(funcs) {
    let result;
    
    return function (arg) {
        result = arg;

        for (let fn of funcs) {
            result = fn(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

And some driver code with the intended result, according to bfe.dev

```
pipe([
  times(2),
  plus(3),
  times(4)
]) 
// (x * 2 + 3) * 4
```

I'm struggling to understand the implementation on a code-level. `pipe` receives an array of functions, and I understand the approach is to walk through the array and compute the result of each function, store that in the `result` variable, similar to an array reduce.

But I cannot wrap my head around how the return function works, and what `arg` would actually be. I would appreciate a line-by-line walkthrough if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example probably needs a bit more to make sense:

```
const doMath = pipe([
  times(2),
  plus(3),
  times(4)
]) 

const finalResult = doMath(5)
console.log(finalResult);
```

`pipe`'s job is to create a new function. That new function has the text:

```
function (arg) {
  result = arg;

  for (let fn of funcs) {
    result = fn(result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

And that is what gets assigned to `doMath` in my example. Then when i call `doMath(5)`, it's going to execute the code, with `arg` equal to 5. It assigns 5 to `result`, and then starts looping through the functions (which it still has access to because this is a closure). Each function calculates a new value, which gets assigned to `result`, and then eventually the final result is returned. So in this case the calculation goes 5 => 10 => 13 => 52. 52 gets returned and then logged out.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the clarification and explanation. The updated example makes it significantly clearer.